# Highlight portion of the text in editor when GoToMarker is applied

Tags: eclipse, markers, eclipse-pde

I have created several markers on a resource on validating it.These markers are logged in Eclipse Markers View. Double click on any marker will navigate the focus on a particular line in the Editor associated with the resource(say for example text editor) because of which the marker has been created.

In the line in focus, is it possible to highlight only a specific portion of the line as the marker would be the result of the validation of a specific pattern in the line.

I tried using  MarkerUtilities.setCharStart(marker, startpost);
              MarkerUtilities.setCharEnd(marker, endPos);

But the problem is then it doesn't go to the actual line even after setting the line number for that marker.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Santhosh

Comment: The character positions are relative to the start of the document

Comment: But How can make it relative to the line and set the proper line number?